# Weka: Is there a Weka function for doing linear (or nonlinear) regression with MULTIVARIATE outputs?

Tags: weka, linear-regression

We are interested in regression where both input and output vectors are
multivariate, in particular linear regression. We know that there is a
linear regression function in Weka that only accepts a single value as the
output. Although we could train a single-output regressor for each output
dimension, this would be very inefficient. We also found a RBFRegressor
function that does RBF regression but again with a single output. Is there
any function for learning linear or nonlinear regression in Weka that
accepts a vector as the output instead of a single value?

We are new to Weka so apologies if we are missing something obvious, but
we couldn't find it in the Weka documentation, textbook, or the web.

Comment: You can try weka-fork Meka  http://meka.sourceforge.net/ . Search For meka here at SO, for related questions and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=weka+meka+multi